# Terminal colors look wrong when using tmux with termite

Tags: terminal, vim, tmux, nvim

The terminal i'm using is **termite**, and it is very good, but i'm having a problem with vim colorschemes and some colors in the terminal itself too when using tmux. It happens as follows: [image: Right = no tmux; Left = tmux] 
As you can see in the screenshot, when i open nvim or vim with tmux, the case on the left, the colorscheme gets altered, this happens with all colorschemes i tested (about 15 or 20). I observed, that when i execute the command `TERM=xterm-256color tmux` right after i enter termite, the nvim/vim (i simlinked my .vimrc, so it is the same as init.vim) colorschemes works like a charm! I'm using i3-gaps, so, i decided to set the binding, **$mod+Return** to open termite that way:

- `bindsym $mod+Return exec termite -e 'TERM=xterm-256color tmux'`

It should have worked, but when i press the keys, the screen only blinks and nothing happens.

Things i've tried include:

- Set `$TERM` to various values, both in termite, in **~/.tmux.conf.local** and in my **.vimrc**: 
    `xterm-256color, screen-256color, termite-256color`;
- Tested the same thing with other terminal emulators, like **xfce-terminal** and **gnome-terminal**, in both it works normally, and the colors get displayed correctly;
- Set in my **.vimrc**:

  ```
  `if &term == "screen"` 

      `set t_Co=256`

  `endif`
  ```
- Starting tmux with `tmux -2`;
- Aliasing in my **.zshrc**:

  ```
  tmux="tmux -2";

  tmux="TERM=xterm-256color tmux" (screen blinks and nothing happens);

  termite="termite --exec "TERM=xterm-256color tmux";

  termite="termite -e "TERM=xterm-256color tmux".
  ```

Edit: The $TERM inside and outside tmux continue to be the same as the terminal. It outputs the same thing when I `echo $TERM` inside and outside tmux. This happened with termite, have to test it with other terminals.

Comment: What's the TERM value set to in `tmux`?  you may need to specify to `tmux` that it's using a 256 color capable terminal, as well as letting `termite` know.

Comment: The TERM in tmux is `screen-256color`. I read in the FAQ, that is not recommend to set it to anything else, I tried, anyway, to set it to other values, with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if anyone is still interested in finding a fix; for those who still have the same problem: I was able to get it working nicely without doing much.

I had forgotten about this matter and stopped using tmux for a long time until I decided to ask about it on a Linux group on Telegram and a cool lad helped me with the issue. We've come up to this, on the `sxhkd` config file:

```
# Open alacritty with tmux
super + shift + Return
    alacritty -e $SHELL -i -c tmux &
```

I changed terminal to `Allacrity`, that's a `GPU-based term`, faster and more easily configurable out-of-the-box, but i don't think that has something to do 
 with, to be fair. Honestly, i don't remember having had the issue with the colors on Alacritty, because, at the time, i didn't used it as it was in beta or something...

You can both add that to a key-binding in your wm's rc, or create an alias for that in your shell rc.

Also, as stated before:

> you need to set the $TERM variable to be the same in your .rc and in
>   .tmux.conf files. To know if something is wrong, i recommend using
>   :checkhealth command inside neovim.

Colors now behave the same in and out of `tmux` :)

The file for the `sxhkd` configuration is on my GitHub, line [06](https://github.com/zSucrilhos/dotfiles/blob/Lyra/nord_dark/.config/sxhkd/sxhkdrc).

I know that necroposting isn't good, but I had to do it as this problem had haunted me for several months, and it was very hard to find a sulution even though i searched in the web on a variety of forums and FAQs, read the docs about the software in question and couldn't find something relevant.

Answer (score 3):

For the ones with a similar problem or the same one here it goes: you just need to set the $TERM variable to be the same in your .rc and in .tmux.conf files. To know if something is wrong, i recommend using `:checkhealth` command inside neovim.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using these configurations in my `~/.tmux.conf` file, should works with you also:

```
set -g terminal-overrides ',xterm-256color:Tc'
set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"
set -as terminal-overrides ',xterm*:sitm=\E[3m'
```

Comment: I tested it now, it doesn't worked... :(

Comment: This worked for me, was almost giving up.